# How to create a text based pdf file for Mac OS x using Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pdf, writer

I am a newbie at Objective-C. I'm trying to create an application that exports user data in form of PDF document on user request. I googled a lot but could not find a way to create a PDF document with text, paragraphs and tables in it. Could anyone please throw some light on this.

Thank you in anticipation.